# Как работают фигурные скобки в Shell Linux?

Tags: linux, shell, find

есть,скажем, команда `find /Users/mac/Downloads/topdf  -exec sh -c "ls -l {}" \;`
вот что выводит:

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

я не понимаю как тут работают фигурные скобки. 
 То есть понятно, что по результату с помощью {} программа выводит листинг про каждый файл, а потом то же самое, но плюс еще и путь к файлу
но что она ставит вместо фигурных скобок ?

что-то типа

```
find /Users/mac/Downloads/topdf  -exec sh -c "ls -l /Users/mac/Downloads/topdf/file1.pdf" \;
```

потом

```
find /Users/mac/Downloads/topdf  -exec sh -c "ls -l /Users/mac/Downloads/topdf/file2.pdf" \;
```

или я не так понимаю ? 
Буду благодарен за объяснение

Comment: Конкретно тут это часть командной строки find и нужно читать документацию по нему, в частности про команду -exec

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Comment: Запускаете в macOS, а спрашиваете почему-то про Linux )

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В данном случае фигурные скобки не имеют отношения к языку оболочки, они интерпретируются исключительно утилитой `find`.

Ключ `-exec` для каждого найденного файла запускает процесс указанный в его параметрах, при этом заменяя строку `{}` на имя аргумента; в данном случае он по очереди запустит:

```
sh -c "ls -l /Users/mac/Downloads/topdf/."
sh -c "ls -l /Users/mac/Downloads/topdf/file1.pdf"
sh -c "ls -l /Users/mac/Downloads/topdf/file2.pdf"
# ... итд
```

**Замечания:**

- Порядок обхода файлов не определён
- Некоторые реализации `find` допускают замену строки '{}' только в случае если она является отдельным аргументом. Для них пришлось бы писать нечто подобное:

  ```
   find -exec sh -c 'ls -l "$0"' '{}' \;
  ```

  К GNU и FreeBSD `find` это не относится.
- Обычно не прибегают к дополнительному вызову `sh` и сразу взывают необходимую утилиту, например `ls`:

  ```
   find -exec ls -l '{}' \;
  ```

  Окромя лучшей производительности у этого способа есть и другое важное преимущество — он корректно обрабатывает файлы с пробелами и/или переводами строк в именах.

---

см. [`man find`](https://www.opennet.ru/man.shtml?topic=find&category=1&russian=2)